# Does printf run in kernel mode or user mode?

Tags: c, operating-system, printf, cpu

The printf function in C is not a system call, but it has to work with system calls in order to output a string.

Thus, could we say that printf runs in kernel mode (privileged CPU mode)?

Comment: If you could say that, you could say that any code that calls `printf` also runs in kernel mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Printf needs to do system calls to output strings because it's unprivileged. If it ran in privileged mode, it wouldn't need system calls in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

No, just because something is calling a kernel mode program does not mean it is also a kernel mode program. Programs using printf are still run in user mode, printf just calls the OS (which is a kernel mode program) to execute parts of printf.

Answer (score 2):

`printf` is a function in the `C` library which is loaded and runs in the user's process, in user mode.

At the point that it invokes the system call to print output to the terminal, the processor transfers control to the kernel and flips the privileged bit at the same time.